# Why form.id returns child input instead of id?

Tags: javascript

In [w3school specification](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_id.asp) it says it should return a string representing the id of element. Replicated this issue on Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0 and Firefox 62.0.2.

```js
element = document.getElementById('form');

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = element.id
document.getElementById('getAttributeResult').innerHTML = element.getAttribute('id')
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" />
</form>
Result of using .id:
<div id="result">
</div>
<br>
Result of using getAttribute:
<div id="getAttributeResult">
</div>
```

Comment: *"In w3school specification..."* w3schools does not specify anything. It's purely a meta-site with an intentionally-misleading name. The specification is done by the WHAT-WG and W3C (which w3schools has no connection with).

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, moving the runnable example **into** the question using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). Your question doesn't have the HTML, so we can't help you explain what you're seeing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the links, I have updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a special behavior on form elements that extends properties for the names of the inputs. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement)

> Named inputs are added to their owner form instance as properties, and can overwrite native properties if they share the same name (eg a form with an input named action will have its action property return that input instead of the form's action HTML attribute).

if you change the input it will work as expected. EG:

```js
element = document.getElementById('form');

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = element.id
document.getElementById('getAttributeResult').innerHTML = element.getAttribute('id')
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="hidden" name="_id" />
</form>
Result of using .id:
<div id="result">
</div>
<br>
Result of using getAttribute:
<div id="getAttributeResult">
</div>
```